# Using SUMO and TraCI: Could not connect to TraCI server 61

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.5, sumo

I am trying to run the traci_tls tutorial with SUMO 0.28.0 on my MacBook Air running MacOS 10.12.1 Sierra.

I created a virtual environment with Python 3.5.2 and copied the traci_tls folder into it. From the terminal I can run `sumo` as well as `sumo-gui` with the file `cross.sumocfg` and that works.
However when I try to run the `runner.py` file I get the following error message:

```
Could not connect to TraCI server at localhost:56666 [Errno 61] Connection refused
 Retrying in 1 seconds
Could not connect to TraCI server at localhost:56666 [Errno 61] Connection refused
 Retrying in 2 seconds

etc...
```

The `SUMO_HOME` environment variable points to `/Users/Isabelle/sumo-0.28.0`, which is where I installed SUMO. I have only this version of SUMO. I build the installation myself and it is configured with TRACI. If I type `sumo` in terminal from within the virtual environment it shows this information:

```
SUMO Version 0.28.0
 Build features: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0 InternalLanes DoublePrecision TRACI PROJ GDAL GUI Python
 Copyright (C) 2001-2016 DLR and contributors; http://sumo.dlr.de
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL Version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 Use --help to get the list of options.
```

I have used TraCI and SUMO outside of the virtual environment before. That resulted in the same error but if I started the sumo-gui via the terminal before I ran `runner.py` it did work. However this fix does not work for me now that I am working within the virtual environment.

I searched the web but haven't been able to find a solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 0.28.0 just came out today. Which version did you use for your tests outside the virtual env? I am asking because the tutorial changed the way it connects to the simulator in 0.28.0. Please retry whether the old version still works.

Comment: That was with 0.27.0. I'll try that version in the virtual env and report back whether it works. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried sumo 0.27.1 in a virtual environment and it works. Although it first mentions that it can't connect, after it automatically retried it worked:
`Could not connect to TraCI server at localhost:8873 [Errno 61] Connection refused
 Retrying in 1 seconds
Loading configuration... done.`

This time I didn't have to run sumo or the sumo-gui beforehand either.

Comment: I tried with a virtualenv and python 3.4 on Linux and it worked. Unfortunately I do not have access to a Mac. Could you try whether the runner.py script from 0.27.1 works when you copy it into 0.28.0 and start it?

Comment: I tried it again today with the runner.py from 0.27.1 and the runner.py from 0.28.0 and now they both work! It does take quite long to connect to the TraCI server, about a minute. So I think either I wasn't waiting long enough before, or maybe something I changed in my system (I have been reorganizing a lot of Python related things) made a difference. Either way thank you very much for your help and my apologies for the false alarm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness I put the answer that arose from the comments here:

Establishing the connection took a lot longer than I expected, leaving it for a minute or so did the job.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

Turn out there was a problem with my host file, and it can be solved by:

1. Update your host file with `127.0.0.1 localhost` (localhost pointed to somewhere else at first)
2. Run SUMO manually then init traci with parameter `host='127.0.0.1'`

Hope that help!

Comment: What host file are you referring to? I can't find anyone